# Cannot test typescript with mocha syntax error

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

I've set up my mocha test command like so

```
mocha --require test/ts-node-hooks.js test/**/*.spec.ts
```

And my `ts-node-hooks.js` file like so

```
const path = require('path');
require("ts-node").register({
    project: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
});
```

My `tsconfig.json` file in the `/test` directory is set to use `ESNEXT` as the javascript target

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ESNEXT",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "types": ["@3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support"]                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
  }
}
```

But I keep getting this error

```
$ mocha --require test/ts-node-hooks.js test/**/*.spec.ts
/src/Call.ts:41
            return (async () => this._callClass = await this.getCallValue('callclass'))();
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

`tsc version 2.6.2` has no problem compiling the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was a simple issue of an existing globally installed `ts-node` that I had forgotten about. Uninstalling that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `mocha -compilers <path to ts-node>` **eg. node_modules\ts-node\register** `test/test-node-hooks.ts`
2. If the above does not work, recompile the .ts file with tsc test-node-hooks.ts and run the mocha command again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, if the issue resurfaces and my answer doesn't fix it, I'll remember this.